# Javafx: set the background of a TreeTableView

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to set the background of a `TreeTableView`.

CSS Styling Used :

```
.tree-table-cell, cell{
   -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
   -fx-background-image: url("blur03.jpg");
}

.tree-table-row-cell{
   -fx-background-image: url("blur03.jpg");
}
```

[image]
here is an implementation of a TreeTableColumn in the treetableview

```
final TreeTableColumn<RootMaster, Integer> dataColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Data");
    dataColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<RootMaster, Integer>("budgetSum"));
    dataColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {
        TreeTableCell<RootMaster, Integer> cell = new TreeTableCell<RootMaster, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return cell ;
    });
```

with this css I get:

```
.tree-table-view, .table-view{
-fx-opacity: 0.3;}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Opacity can help you to make it a little transparent to show the parent behind it.

Inline CSS:

```
tableView.setStyle(
"-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 100, 100, 0.5);
-fx-background-radius: 10;"
);
```

Seperate CSS file:

```
.tree-table-view, .table-view{
-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 100, 100, 0.5);
}
```

In the above code, 0.5 specifies the opacity or alpha property of the node. A value of 0.5 makes it half opaque. Thus the value of a ranges from 0 to 1 where 1 is fully visible and 0 is fully opaque.

Comment: when I apply it with rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) on tree-table-cell; it became all black, but when i set the background image IT works, except that the image is applied to each cell in a row, and what i want is that the image get applied to ALL the treetableview, not repeated. i will post a picture. Thanks for replying

Comment: If you want transparency and display VBox, why are you adding an image? if you want to have transparency while using a background image, `-fx-background-color:transparent`is the way to go. Although you must check that the image is a valid image that can be made trasparent. Png files allow transparency. Maybe try that.

Comment: the background of the vbox is a picture, and since I could not make the treetableview transparent so it shows the VBox background; I'm trying now to set the background of the treetableview directly (with the image that is the background of the VBox); that's why now i'm trying to do it differently. i will update my question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this css styling:

```
.tree-table-row-cell {
    -fx-background: transparent;
}

.tree-table-view {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Tested with:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage stage )
{
    TreeItem<String> childNode1 = new TreeItem<>( "Node 1" );
    TreeItem<String> childNode2 = new TreeItem<>( "Node 2" );
    TreeItem<String> childNode3 = new TreeItem<>( "Node 3" );

    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>( "Root" );
    root.setExpanded( true );

    root.getChildren().setAll( childNode1, childNode2, childNode3 );

    TreeTableColumn<String, String> column = new TreeTableColumn<>( "Column" );
    column.setPrefWidth( 150 );

    column.setCellValueFactory( ( TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String, String> p ) 
            -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper( p.getValue().getValue() ) );

    TreeTableView<String> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>( root );
    treeTableView.getColumns().add( column );


    VBox box = new VBox( treeTableView, new Button( "test" ) );
    box.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: green" );

    final Scene scene = new Scene( box, 200, 400 );
    scene.getStylesheets().add( "path/to/the-style-above.css" );
    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Do you have custom cellFactories?

Comment: I update the question, you can see the implementation, Thanks for your reply

Comment: @usertest you can also test it on (Example 15-2 Creating a TreeTableView Component With Two Columns)[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm#CJABIIDJ]. Just copy paste the code and add the css to the scene.